# Mouse hover when mouse is idle

Tags: macos, cocoa, mouseevent

My apps need to detect that mouse is not having any action or idle for some time to hide a view. I am working on Mac OS X application. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `NSTimer` that hides the view after x seconds.

Track the mouse by adding a `NSTrackingArea` on top of your window. Or if you want all events subclass `NSApplication` and overwrite `sendEvent`. Reset the timer when you receive an event.